# Duplicate values appended in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

so I'm creating an App with Swift 2 and Xcode 7 and using Parse as my backend service.
I have two view controllers, a `PFQueryTableViewController` to show a list of PFObjects and the other the show the detail of selected cells.
I figured the way to do that is to append a unique object id to an array, and then to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to perform segue.
But I'm having problems with append elements to the array here. Overtime I append and print the array, it shows elements 2 times. So if the correct array is [1,2,3,4], then what i'm getting is [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4], really weird.

```
var arrayOfGameId = [String]()
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? PFTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
    if let object = object {
        cell!.textLabel?.text = object["Title"] as? String
        cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = object["Platform"] as? String
        if let thumbnail = object["Image"]! as? PFFile {
            cell!.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "game1.png")
            cell!.imageView!.file = thumbnail
        }
        let gameid = object["GameId"] as! String!
        arrayOfGameId.append(gameid)
    }
    print(arrayOfGameId)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `PFQueryTableViewController` there is no need to make your own list of objectIds.

The returned `PFObjects` from `queryForTable` are automatically stored in a list called `objects`.

If you need to get the selected object, and segue to a detail view controller, you actually don't even need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, try the following.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController]
    var detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController

    // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)

        // selectedObject is the PFObject to be displayed
        detailsVC.selectedObject = (objects?[row] as! PFObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote if helpful and mark as answer if your problem has been resolved